# how to change splash screen (loading screen) in unity 3d free version

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, mono

I created a new project in Unity 3D, and then exported it to Xcode. Now I want to change the launch image from Xcode but I can not.

I can see this error:

```
***`abortOnInvalidSplashscreen() at VerifyiPhoneSplashScreen.cpp:80:
0xd48238:  push   {r7, lr}
0xd4823c:  movw   r0, #0xc7c2
0xd48240:  mov    r7, sp
0xd48244:  movt   r0, #0x7d
0xd48248:  add    r0, pc, r0
0xd4824c:  bl     0xf8c5e4                  ; printf_console at LogAssert.cpp:763
0xd48250:  mov    lr, pc
0xd48254:  b      0x1511558                 ; symbol stub for: abort
```

Log print:

```
2015-04-09 16:53:26.475 *****[4194:679693] -> registered mono modules 0x15ac440 -> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2015-04-09 16:53:26.950 *****[4194:679693] LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad
2015-04-09 16:53:26.952 *****[4194:679693] /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BDDF20E1-C230-4114-A57B-207BEC0C7C3C/*****.app/LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
Mono path[0] = '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BDDF20E1-C230-4114-A57B-207BEC0C7C3C/*****.app/Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BDDF20E1-C230-4114-A57B-207BEC0C7C3C/*****.app/Data/Managed'
You are using Unity iPhone Basic. You are not allowed to remove the Unity splash screen from your game
```

Comment: I mean, that error is pretty self explanatory, you're not allowed to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that with the Pro Version. It's a specific limitation of the free version. The Pro version you can get with discounted iOS plugin prices from Studica if you're a student with a .edu account. The Pro Version with iOS extensions is totally worth the extra $$.